# TSQL order by / convert with compare operator

Tags: t-sql

I would like to have a construction like this:

... order by ([datetimefield-1] > getdate() AS MyBoolean) desc, [field-2]

So all dates that are > now should be first in the order BUT it should not ordered by the date itself, because there ist a second column which will give the final oder. The datetimefield-1 should be True if it is in the future and false if not (or if it is NULL). And this true or false should then the value to preorder it so that all records where the date is in the future are on top.

The syntax here is wrong, but I guess it is possible with the right.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
order by case 
           when datetimefield > dateadd(day, 1, getdate())
           then 0 
           else 1 
         end, 
         YourOtherColumn
```